# Install Kubernetes (kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet) on debian stretch

Tags: kubernetes, debian-stretch

I would like to install Kubernetes on my debian machine:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:        9.5
Codename:       stretch
```

Looking into google deb package archive I only find the package for "kubectl", nothing else:

https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Comparing to ubuntu xenial many packages are missing. Could someone be so kind and give me more information how to deal with this ? Is it possible to install kubeadm and kubelet on debian stretch too ?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl

Thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to install kubeadm and kubelet on debian stretch too ?

Yes it is! Please refer to the helpful guide that you linked at the end of your question: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl

Here is the relevant part:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

Note, that you are using kubernetes-xenial above, not kubernetes-stretch.

Do not forget to install docker first, for how, see the same linked page above.

Comment: The kubernetes-stretch repo only seems to contain kubectl : https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/kubernetes-stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Comment: @Tolan, that's what the OP says `Looking into google deb package archive I only find the package for "kubectl", nothing else` and that's what I say as well `Note, that you are using kubernetes-xenial above, not kubernetes-stretch`. So thank you for triple-confirming it ;)

Answer (score 1):

As of K8S 1.18.5 I am not aware of any official DEB package from Google unfortunately. I would highly recommend you build your own DEB package on Debian Stretch. I have created 2 examples on how to do so with Debian 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 at https://github.com/runlevel5/kubernetes-packages.

Answer (score 1):

try with this step

- `sudo apt install curl apt-transport-https -y`
- `curl -fsSL  https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg|sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/k8s.gpg`
- `curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
- `echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`
- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt install wget curl vim git kubelet kubeadm kubectl -y`
- `sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl`

and finally, Confirm installation by checking the version of kubectl.
`kubectl version --client && kubeadm version`

after checking the logs must be something like this.

```
    Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.3", GitCommit:"aef86a93758dc3cb2c658dd9657ab4ad4afc21cb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-07-13T14:30:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.3", GitCommit:"aef86a93758dc3cb2c658dd9657ab4ad4afc21cb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-07-13T14:29:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```